# Rspec-mocks doesn't raise the exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-mocks

I have this piece of RoR code that creates a gitlab repository. If the repository already exists, the method returns false with the error message.

```ruby
class CreateRepositoryJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(id)
    namespace = Gitlab.create_group("applications", "applications")        
    begin
      repo = Gitlab.create_project(id, namespace_id: namespace.id).to_hash.symbolize_keys
      [true, repo]
    rescue Gitlab::Error::BadRequest => e
      [false, e]
    end
  end
end
```

```

I would like to test this method, in particular when the repository already exists. I use rspec-mocks and this is what I have:

```ruby
it "cannot be created because the repository already exists" do
   # some mocks...
   allow(Gitlab).to receive(:create_project).with(anything).and_raise(Gitlab::Error::BadRequest)
   added, repo = CreateRepositoryJob.perform_now entity, entity_directory
   expect(added).to be false
end
```

The test returns **true**. It seems like the exception is not triggered.

Any idea what's going on ?

Comment: what happens when you change `allow(GitLab)` into `expect(GitLab)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the issue was **the initialization of the Gitlab::Error::BadRequest object**.

```
it "raise an exception for the second repository" do
  # some mocks...
  allow(Gitlab).to receive(:create_project).with(anything, anything).and_raise(Gitlab::Error::BadRequest.new(double(parsed_response: "error", code: 404, request: request)))
  added, _ = CreateRepositoryJob.perform_now  entity, entity_directory
  expect(added).to be false
end
```

```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a block when checking for exceptions.

```
expect { added }.to raise_error(Gitlab::Error::BadRequest)
```

Try and update the code to match your needs.

More info can be found here: https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher

Comment: I know, the issue here is I can't mock a function that will raise an exception.